# How to enable autocomplete/syntax-highlight for PHP core functions in Eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, autocomplete

I searched a lot, checked many times the neccesary steps, but it still don't work.

My environment is :

1. Latest eclipse for PHP developer package
2. Project is newed, not check out directly from SVN
3. .project has a line

   > ```
   > <nature>org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature</nature>
   > ```
4. .buildpath has a line

   > ```
   > <buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
   > ```
5. .settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
   has a line

   > ```
   > include_path=0;/projectname
   > ```
6. file ensured opened in PHP Editor

Something works:

1. PHP core function defination displayed when mouse over, and Ctrl+Click will open its defined file, but input 'arr' nothing happens, while a list of array functions expected
2. Autocomplete does work for internal functios/variables such as class members
   But never works for PHP core functions, neither syntax highlighting

Answer (score 30):

Right-Click on your project -> Configure -> Add PHP Support...

Works for me on Eclipse 3.5 / PDT 2.1

Comment: ever checked this option, it's gray

Comment: wow thanks, this worked for me on Galileo, it's a pain to work without autocomplete for core features

Comment: I don't see a 'configure' option when I right-click my project in Helios

Comment: Don't forget to add <?php ?> tags too!

Comment: After you install support for PHP, restarting wasn't enough for me - I had to close any already open files in the editor and then restart and re-open them for the syntax highlighting to work (Eclipse Luna)

Comment: Oxygen (Release 4.7.0) doesn't have "add PHP Support" option in the context menu. In my case, editing the [.buildpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23788136/1677209) file worked.

Answer (score 22):

For me, nothing worked, except:

1. Backup and then delete the .db files under: /.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2/
2. Restart eclipse.

I got this tip from #4 in: http://www.nwiresoftware.com/blogs/nwire/2010/09/five-tips-speeding-eclipse-pdt-and-nwire

Comment: Worked great, just by deleting the .db files and restarting. Thanks

Comment: Worked for Eclipse 4.3 when the add PHP support option was disabled.

Comment: Excellent advice. Does anybody know how and where one would trigger such an reindexing of DLTK within Eclipse? Helped me big time with Eclipse Kepler and PDT 3.2.0! thx

Answer (score 15):

As noted before the 'natures' node for php core is listed but this is most insufficient when the project is imported or checked out.

- Make a backup of your .project
- Remove the 'natures' node children
- Close/Re-open eclipse
- Right-click project -> Configure -> Add PHP Support
- Add back other 'natures' children

The issue is that project will not make the necessary imports because it assumes it already has.

Comment: `Right-click project -> Configure -> Add PHP Support` is always grayed out for me?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing helped, but this:

In Eclipse:

Go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations

Click Add

Type *.php

Under Associated Editors choose PHP Editor and click Default on the right.

Close and open your php file.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 .dll files: model.h2.db, model.lock.db and model.trace.db under workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2

Remove these files and restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to still be a lot of bugs related to auto-completion for the [**PHP Development Tools Project (PDT)**](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/index.php) (See [Open Bugs](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?query_format=advanced&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr&short_desc=&product=PDT&long_desc_type=allwordssubstr&long_desc=&bug_file_loc_type=allwordssubstr&bug_file_loc=&status_whiteboard_type=allwordssubstr&status_whiteboard=&keywords_type=allwords&keywords=&bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&emailtype1=substring&email1=&emailtype2=substring&email2=&bugidtype=include&bug_id=&votes=&chfieldfrom=&chfieldto=Now&chfieldvalue=&cmdtype=doit&order=Reuse+same+sort+as+last+time&field0-0-0=noop&type0-0-0=noop&value0-0-0=)).

One has been entered two days ago: [bug 286733](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=286733) "When using sub namespace completion does not work."

[image]

But this is hardly the only one:

- "Autocomplete on namespaces failed" ([bug 281766](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=281766))
- "`[`php 5.3`]` Code assist doesn't provide method completion" ([bug 286068](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=286068))
- ...

They are all related to the namespace of the PHP code. Could you check if you reproduce the error in a global namespace?

Comment: not this one, in my project (no namespace specified), also tried a clean PHP project, autocomplete does work for class members, just no effect when input core functions.

Answer (score 0):

If issue is still exists, follow the following steps:

1. Remove project from eclipse.
2. Goto your project folder and remove .Settings folder and .project
   file.
3. Again import php project with different name.

it's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click on your project -> Configure -> Convert to PHP Project...

Works for me on Eclipse 4.6 / PDT 5.2