# Eclipse PDT Autocomplete

Tags: php, eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-pdt

I have tried for several days now to get autocomplete working.

I have a clean install of Eclipse PDT and another with plugins like aptana and subversion, but neither works with autocomplete.

What do I have to do to get autocomplete working? Do i need some shortcut for this? In Netbeans it is working without a shortcut...and [this video](http://www.videomeli.com/video/60HG0KaRLMo/eclipse-pdt-var-declaration-autocomplete-example.html) looks like its working in eclipse too.

Thanks for any hints and help ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me, when using PDT, when I begin to type a variable, I can do Ctrl-space and I get a list of matching defined variables in my code. I believe you can get the list automatically. If you go `Window » Preferences`, then find PHP in the left column. Expand PHP, expand Editor, and select Code Assist. I believe Auto Activation is the option to pop up the autocomplete automatically.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i just found the solution myself...i did exact the same like you said. ;)

Answer (score 6):

I tried to follow the accepted answer with no use. Then I found answer [to this question in another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1298290/18297). Basically all you need to do is right click on the project and go to Configure > Add PHP support. If that option is grayed out then you already marked project as the PDT project.

Answer (score 1):

hint: check General > Editors > File Associations > *.php (*.phtml,...) if default editor is "PHP Editor"

Answer (score 0):

ok, i found the solution now. if anyone else has same problems here is the way:
go to window->preferences->PHP->Editor->Code Assist

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

Right click on you project in the project Explorer » Configure » Add PHP support...

[image]