# How do I add the PHP libraries to my basic remote project in eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-studio, eclipse-pdt, include-path

I have a basic project that was created from a remote system using the eclipse tools to setup that connection. I right clicked on the folder on my remote system and chose create a new project. Now, I want to add PHP to the build path, but it is just a basic project. How do I quickly add those libraries with Eclipse PDT or Zend Studio installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this what you are looking for, but try

- Right click the project folder in the Explorer and click *Open Project*.
- Right click the project folder again.
- Find and click *Configure* from the Context Menu
- In the submenu find and click *Add PHP Support*

In case you want to configure the `include_path`:

- Right click the project folder in the Explorer and click *Open Project*.
- Right click the project folder again.
- Find and click *Include Path* from the context menu
- In the submenu find and click *Configure Include Path*
- Add any resources you need in the tabbed dialog

If both of this is not what you are looking for, please clarify the question.

Answer (score 6):

When Add PHP Support is disabled but PHP libraries are not included.

1. Right Click and Open project.
2. Find .buildpath file.
3. add the follwing code to it.

Code:

```
<buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
```

Comment: What if we don't have a .buildpath file?

Comment: @Salketer right click on project -> Build Path > Configure Build Path... click "Add Folder", select the project root directory. Click ok. You should now have a `.buildpath` file

Answer (score 0):

If there's no file `.buildpath` in the project's folder (and no "Buildpath" option to be found in the project's context menu), then just create a new file `.buildpath` with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<buildpath>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path=""/>
    <buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
</buildpath>
```