# Eclipse Kepler with RSE and TYPO3 code completion

Tags: eclipse, typo3, code-completion

For TYPO3 Development I use Eclipse Standard/SDK version "Kepler".
For accessing TYPO3 files on a remote server I use the Remote System Explorer (RSE) plugin, accesing the files via SSH.

I managed to add PHP code completion for the RSE. Works fine.

Now I wondered if it is possible to add the TYPO3 API in code completion using the RSE plugin.

I dont have local TYPO3 projects, but I could image downloading the TYPO3 core and placing it in a local folder for referencing all the possible classes and methods.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: For extbase, see http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/1-Installation/3-configuring-your-ide.html

Comment: This explains how to set autocompletion on a PHP project. I dont have PHP projects. I use RSE to modify files on a remote server. No projects there. Only files.

Comment: TYPO3 is a PHP Project

Comment: I very well know this. I am talking about Eclipse PHP Projects. I dont have a Eclipse PHP Project File on the server. I just access a remote directory using RSE. I do not have a Eclipse PHP project file on the server.

Comment: I am not familiar with eclipse or any IDE, but in similar use cases (to run CodeKit and git locally) I just had to see that I'm better off creating local copies of the material I'm working with. Then it's just a question of setting "upload on save" in the editor (or IDE). In my case, I had to switch to Sublime from Coda for that feature. So I'm still testing my project remotely, but the necessary files are local. Also, I get free backup with that.

Comment: We manage over 80 TYPO3 projects, with some of them having multiple GB in data. Also my local computer, does not have the same configuration as the server. To cut a long story short, we wont change our whole development process, just because I want code completion in Eclipse (which by the way is not used by everybody in my team).

Comment: Misunderstanding - I don't mean that I run stuff locally. I run TYPO3 on a remote server and edit (only) the templates and custom extensions locally, uploading them on each save. No local server and/or configuration required. If I wanted extbase code completion, I would download extbase for the IDE to use it as reference for code completion.  As you wrote "I could image downloading the TYPO3 core", maybe you can edit your question to make clear that this is *not* what you want to do - so someone else can help you. Cheers

Comment: I still could image downloading the TYPO3 core locally. But still I have no working example, on how to get code completion with TYPO3 using RSE working on remote filesystems.

Comment: At least with PhpStorm, I can download PHP files and specify their directory as library folder. I am pretty sure that Eclipse offers the same feature. Therefore download the core and specify it as library. Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421231/how-do-i-add-the-php-libraries-to-my-basic-remote-project-in-eclipse