# No PHP functions types etc. in Zend Studio 9

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-studio

I'm planning to move to Zend Studio 9 and installed the trial version parallel to my Version 8.
Now I loaded my old Workspace and my Zend Framework project didn't know anything about php.

For example if I try to extend an exception, it says: "Cannot extend from interface exception".
Or 'file_get_contents' ends in: 'Call of undefined function.

So it seems no PHP definitions are loaded but how can I change that? In the Zend Studio 8 it still works.

Comment: Right click the project folder. Click *Configure* and then *Add PHP Support*. If that doesnt fix it, try http://kb.zend.com/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=415 (yes, I know its for ZS7)

Comment: Hmm, then try Project > Clean

Comment: Yes, i tried that, too. Now event Zend Studio 8 has this problem. Strange. btw. when i create i new project is has the problem, too.

Comment: I assume this has something to do with the .build files as indicated the kb article. You could ask the official support at http://forums.zend.com/viewforum.php?f=59. Do you want me to put anything of the above or all as an answer?

Comment: Are you sure this thread doesn't have the solution for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293762/how-to-enable-autocomplete-syntax-highlight-for-php-core-functions-in-eclipse

Comment: Thanks, now it wordked. But not the popular answers in this thread. What actualy helped was to delete the database files in  /.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core

Answer (score 1):

I did the same, transfer workspace from Zend Studios 8 to Zend Studio 9.
It worked fine on Ubuntu but it did not work Windows 7...

Anyway I highly recommend to start with a fresh workspace, to not bring over old settings from Zend Studios 8.

Comment: Yes thats what i planning to do after finishing my current project. The move to Zend Studio 9 isn't neccesary that badly.

Comment: Ok, no i had the time to test out this solution. I intalled the 7.0.1 trial and created a new Workspace. Then i copied a old project into the workspace (without project settings) and created a new php projet for this folder. This didn't solved the problem.

Comment: can you create a project from existing sources? instead of copying the project folder, create a new one using the sources from the old one

Comment: You cannot copy a project like that, there are hidden files in the workspace it self that manages other settings for the workspace.

Comment: I removed all hidden Files in the project folder.

Comment: Thats the thing you cannot do that. Those files are needed to "setup" the project in Zend Studios

Answer (score 0):

look into your .project file. Did you have a

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature</nature>
</natures>
```

section. If not add it.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying files of ZendFramework Files in Php folder.Also From Bin Folder of Zend Framework copy 2 Files zf batch files & zf script file in php folder.And Also include the path in php.ini file.