# Eclipse autocomplete is not working for PHP-project

Tags: php, eclipse, autocomplete

My Eclipse doesn't use auto-complete... My colleague get a whole list of suggestions by just typing some letters and I get nothing...

The Eclipse version I use is:

```
Eclipse for PHP Developers

Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110301-1815

(c) Copyright Eclipse contributors and others 2000, 2011.  All rights reserved.
Visit http://eclipse.org/
```

And I think I've set all available settings for autocomplete.
I lose a huge amount of time every time I have to search for the correct naming. Is there any module of software I've to install extra to get this autocompletion?

Comment: Is it only your own functions etc that aren't autocompleting, or the native PHP ones, too?

Comment: Please see [How to enable autocomplete/syntax-highlight for PHP core functions in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1293762/367456).

Comment: @Narcissus, native PHP functions too...

Comment: @hakre, thanks for the links. I'll check into that!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok, found the solution! Apparently I had to "Add PHP support" in the properties window of the project. Thanks for all the help though!

[image]

Comment: Just a little addition here: I had to `Build Project` after enabling PHP support.

And thanks for figuring this out, it's been bugging (hehe) me for weeks after a re-install.

Comment: in my case what worked for me was `Enable Zend Framework Support`.  I did not have `Add PHP Support` in my drop down

Comment: Mine said "Convert to PHP project", but yeah, this is the only thing that finally worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

Generally this can be activated by enabling *Content Assist*. It can be found on *Window-Preference->PHP->Editor->Content Assist*

1. Setup your `php_include_path`. Go to the *properties* of the project. Then *PHP Include Path*.
2. If you have any **external library** add it there too (I use *Zend* and *Kohana*).

Comment: Right click on your project and click properties. On the left pane you should see *PHP Include Path*. See this image. http://tinypic.com/r/9kmtd1/5

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I don't have such a link in my properties... I found the solution though!

Answer (score 11):

I did it by deleting ".metadata" directory on my main workspace :D

Answer (score 3):

I can try ALL answers (from this and others threads), only work for me delete (or rename for backup) `.metadata` folder on workspace folder

1. Close eclipse
2. `mv .metadata .metadata_older`
3. Start eclipse (clean start wrokspace of eclipse, none project are listed)
4. Import from workspace your project
5. Eclipse rebuild and refresh works (several project settings are lost!!!)
6. Autocompletion, follow code, etc now work.

This isn't the ideal solution, but is the ONLY solution for me, I migrated from eclipse 3.6 to 4.4 in one step, and PHP support is gone, only highlight code are working until delete `.metadata` folder.

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 Java 1.7 ORACLE

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check the options in Windows preferences for content assist. It might be disabled. It probably would be php -> Editor -> Content Assist and see what is selected for auto activation.

Comment: Yep, it's enabled (after 2ms) and the Options are set on `Completion Inserts`

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Eclipse, but I know in Netbeans (and other IDE's) you can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to bring up the auto complete window after you start typing a function/variable.

Give that a try.

Comment: Changing IDE is not a solution and OP didn't asked that. Moreover It can be done in Eclipse too.

Comment: @Shiplu: You should read the answer more properly, it's not suggesting to switch IDEs but to try a common keyboard shortcut. And a good one, it's the same in PDT.

Comment: @hakre Oops! My bad. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens only for one project in Eclipse and others are autocompleting correctly, it sometimes happen when you create new PHP project and press `Finish` on the first page.

To fix it, remove the project from Eclipse (`Windows > Show view > Navigator` and press `DELETE` on the project). Then go to project folder and delete file `.project` and folder `.setting`.

In Eclipse now select `File > New > PHP project`, select name and folder, press `Next` and verify (or manually add) that root folder of the project is listen on `Source` tab.

Then click `Next` and add root folder of the project or folders that contain PHP files into `Build path`. Now you can click `Finish`.

*Note: adding `Source` and `Build` paths into existing project usually does not fix this problem and you really have to delete and create new project.*

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project -> Properties -> PHP -> Validation

Check the Enable prockect specific settings

Select PHP Ver

Answer (score 0):

Check your **.buildpath**, try build something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<buildpath>
    <buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path="vendor"/>
    <buildpathentry external="true" kind="lib" path="common-libs/vendor/project-sample/lib"/>
</buildpath>
```

Comment: Is this still an issue? I'm trying figure out when this happen, but I can not reproduce :(

Comment: If you're using Linux try change path="common-libs/vendor/project-sample/lib" by path="C:\common-libs\vendor\project-sample\lib", after that open your Eclipse. You will reproduce the problem.