# eclipse 4.3 autocomplete phpunit 4.x

Tags: php, eclipse, autocomplete, phpunit

I have installed eclipse Kepler 4.3 and phpunit 4.1 using composer, (I am not using PEAR at all).
The variables are all in my path, (added by composer).

phpunit from the command line works just fine.

But eclipse still cannot recognise the php code/classes, this makes developing a bit more tedious than I used to.

I have tried to add the */path/composer/vendor* path to my external path in eclipse, but the path is not picked up.

Any suggestions on how I could add autocomplete to eclipse?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574962/eclipse-autocomplete-is-not-working-for-php-project?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

In the case you tried to add the phar file as a library and it didn't work, you could get the source from https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit and add its src as a user Library in Eclipse. Then, include that library into your project. That'll do the trick.